# Homeomorphism proof

Tags: general-topology

> $\mathbb{R}^2-(0 \times \mathbb{R}_+) \approx \mathbb{R}^2$

Now consider the map that sends the line $(-1 \times \mathbb{R}_+)$ to $(0 \times \mathbb{R}_+)$. And then continue this inductively. Every function is a map, because it is a translation. The composition of any finite number of maps is a map. The question I have is whether the countably infinite composition of these maps is a map. Thank you.

Comment: There's no meaningful definition of an infinite composition of maps. If $s(n)=n+1$ then what does the map $s^{\infty}$ map $n$ to?

Comment: In the plane you can find simple homeomorphisms: first contract $R^2$ onto $R^*_+\times R$ via $(x,y)\mapsto(e^x,y)$, and then take the square by identifying the real plane with the complex numbers: $z\mapsto z^2$. This will give you a homeomorphism $R^2\to R^2\setminus R_-\times 0$ which you can then rotate to where you want it.

Comment: I guess, @Mike meant the map $(n,x)\mapsto (n+1,x)$ if $n\in\Bbb Z,\ n<0$ and $x>0$.

Comment: @Berci: yeah, that's basically what I meant. Additionally, all other points are mapped to themselves.

Comment: But this is **not continuous** on points of $\{n\}\times\Bbb R^{\ge 0}$ for $n<0,\,n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is not bad, and it certainly works as a *bijection* between the given *sets*.

But the defined map is not going to be *continuous*.

**Hint:** Use polar coordinates, the angle measured starting from the given ray $\{0\}\times\Bbb R^+$ (i.e. the $y$-axis), then deform the angles from $(0,360^\circ)$ to $(90^\circ,270^\circ)$, thus you get the open half plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume you mean that the infinite composition isn't continuous? If so, how do you know this?

Comment: Exactly what would be your final map?

Comment: Well, I've basically defined it recursively. The first map sends the open line starting at -1 to 0. Then the second sends the one starting at -2 to -1. The desired map is then the infinite composition of these maps.

Comment: What is the image of the point $(0,-1)$ under this 'map'? If you can't answer this question then it is not a map.

Comment: Defining a recursive **sequence** of maps does not automatically produce some kind of infinite composition.

Comment: @Mike, I still can't think anything else, that you are describing the single function which takes $(n,x)\mapsto (n+1,x)$ whenever $n<0,\ n\in\Bbb Z$ and $x>0$, *and* fixes all other $(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So, is this map continuous and if so, can you prove it? Or provide a counterexample.

Comment: This map is not continuous, but it doesn't mean that the given spaces are not homeomorphic. I gave you a hint how to find a homeomorphism.

Comment: I'd really like to see a counterexample, please. Can you give me some open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose inverse under my function isn't open? The whole point of the question was whether the function is continuous or not.

Comment: @Mike a small ball around $(0,0)$ has non-open preimage because the preimage has two connected components, one of which is the single point $\{(-1,0)\}$.

Comment: If your question is *continuity*, you should have written it in the body of the question...